# Active serializer models, setting custom key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

Im currently working on a application, using emberjs and rails, via REST.

Also i'm using the active_model_serializer gem, for representing my data, but after the upgrading EmberData to Beta3, the json expecting structure for associations was changed.

Before when pointing to a association, the key would be

```
"object_ids":[1,2]
```

But now ember data expects, the object in plural

```
"objects": [1,2]
```

The problem is then, how do i format it this way using active_model_serializer?

My model

```
class ServiceField < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end
```

And the serializer object

```
class ServiceFieldSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description
  has_many :services
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

But this generates

```
service_ids: [1,2]
```

Is there a convenient way to accomplish the plural version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associations accept the `key` option, so you can do the following:

```
has_many :services, :key => "services"
```

I suspect AMS will be updated to this syntax by default at some point, since both ember-data and AMS are in close orbit to the json api standard that folks are putting together.

Comment: That's not surprising. Unfortunately, SO still doesn't have versioned answers.